# The connection of linear algebra with geometry

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

I started learning linear algebra from [This freely available book](https://www.google.com.np/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiR_eHuvY3TAhWBRhQKHR6dD8sQFggZMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flinear.ups.edu%2Fdownload%2F0200waldron.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG2ZcZR21CD0-qk4dPSEXFF17nMhg), and in it the author says that a course in linear algebra can be very fruitful if the subject emphasizes logic in two or three dimensions(I think this means interpreting things practically, logically and/or pictorially), which he says, is not done in the book(mentioned above).
Since I want to lay a solid foundation to my understanding, I'd like to have *this* fruitful beginning. Is there a book that takes such an approach to it's account?

Comment: I am interested in this as well.

Comment: It sounds like what the book is saying is that it's best to have a foundation in more basic vector geometry in two or three dimensions before studying the kind of linear algebra in that book. If that's what's meant, then a book like *Elementary Vector Algebra* by Macbeath might be what you want. A slightly more advanced book, that includes a lot of linear algebra with matrices, but restricted to dimensions 2 and 3, would be *Pure Mathematics, Vols. 1, 2,* by Parsonson, looking only at the chapters on vectors and matrices.

Comment: @user49640 , by _vector geometry_  does it mean things like "dot product, cross products" and stuffs alike or is there a complete new field out there?

Comment: That's pretty much what I have in mind, with applications to proving geometric theorems as well, possibly studying conic sections, etc. It could also include linear transformations in dimension 2 or 3, as well as determinants. But I'm not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: @user49640, in high school matrices and vectors were completely seperated and also seperated well aside from algebra, I'm very confused how these relate and don't know how to start with linear algebra itself. Like it needing some knowledge from vectors or sth?

Comment: Different books present linear algebra differently. I'm not really familiar with the book you're using, but other books start with vector geometry before studying matrix algebra. That's the order I learned things in, and I found it helpful, but if a book says it doesn't have it as a prerequisite, then you can most likely trust that that's correct.